# Passing PHP array from external php file to script tags on the main page

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays

Am trying to pass a variable from an external php script to scripts tag in the main page but the main_page.php is returning an undefined variable which is the array that i intend to pass from PHP to js. Its a university units registration system, any help will be greatly appreciated.
my javascript is

```
<script>
var m=<?php echo json_encode($ar) ?>;
alert(m[0]);
</script>
```

And my PHP file with the array variable ($ar) is this

```
<?php
$course=$semester="";
$course_err=$semester_err="";
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","courses");
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    if(empty(trim($_POST["name"]))){
        $course_err= "course  is not set";
    } else {
        $course=($_POST["name"]);
    }

    if(empty(trim($_POST["email"]))){
    $semester_err= "semester is not set";
    } else {
        $semester=($_POST["email"]);
    }
}

if(empty($course_err || $semester_err)){
    $sql="SELECT `$semester`  FROM  `$course`";
    $retval=mysqli_query($link,$sql);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($retval)>0){
    while ($row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($retval)){
        echo "<form method='post' name='units'>";
        echo "<li class='list-group-item' style='background:#663300;color:#fff'> 
        <input type='checkbox' id='firstnit'><p style='color:#fff;font- 
        size:1.2em;'>{$row[$semester]}</p></li><br>";
        echo "</form>";

        $ar=array($row);
        $_SESSION["tempArray"]=$ar;
        echo json_encode($ar);
    }
    }else{
        echo "<li class='list-group-item' style='color:#111;'>0 units 
        registered</li>";
    }

    echo "<script>alert('The units have been added to the iframe with success');
    </script>";
    echo "<br/>";
    echo "<button onclick='Array()' class='btn'>Submit Units</button>";

}

?>
```

Comment: How is `$ar` passed from the source file to the HTML file?

Comment: Thats exactly what am asking?

Comment: How about `<?php include 'your other file.php'; ?>` before the `<script>` block?

Comment: Serialize your session with $_SESSION["tempArray"]=serialize($ar) instead of $_SESSION["tempArray"]=$ar; and in your PHP you have to unserialize the $_SESSION['tempArray'].

Comment: @bestprogrammer,   will try to do that

Comment: I Okay how do I echo every Single value of a column,  that's my last resort.  Because if I can echo each element of an array with its own unique Id then am good to go

Comment: foreach($array['key'] as $item) {.... }